# Javascript: How to get Items for each ClassName

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, loops

I need some help on the following HTML, I having a difficult time getting an result from loop on this :
HTML:

```
<tr id='row1'>
    <td><input type="text" class="col1"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="col1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr id='row3'>
    <td><input type="text" class="col3"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="col3"/></td>
</tr>
<tr id='row4'>
    <td><input type="text" class="col4"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="col4"/></td>
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
var trow = $("[id*=row]").length;
for (var i = 1; i <= trow; i++) {
    var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('col'+i);
    item = [].map.call(rows, function( row ){
        return row.value;
    });
    var ItemSet = item.join('{}');
    alert(ItemSet);
};
```

The loop stops on the 2nd loop I think It's because on the row limit/length.I can't think of other loop on this one. Thankss for the help!

Comment: when `i=2`, there is no elements with class name `col2`

Comment: Yes I know, but how will it continue to the next loop? or is there a different way of loop to get the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is relying on incrementing the value of `i` while there's no `<input type="text" class="col2"/>` after `<input type="text" class="col1"/>`.

Assuming that the `id` of all `<tr>` tags begins with `row` and followed by a positive integer i.e `row1`,`row3`, and so on, consider the following HTML where you put the values in textboxes inside the columns

```
<table>
  <tr id='row1'>
    <td><input type="text" class="col1" value="DEMO1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="col1" value="DEMO2" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='row3'>
    <td><input type="text" class="col3" value="DEMO3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="col3" value="DEMO4" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='row4'>
    <td><input type="text" class="col4" value="DEMO5" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="col4" value="DEMO6" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can use [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) as follows:

```
$("tr[id^=row]").each(function() {

    // get the index
    var index = $(this).attr("id").replace('row', '');

    // loop through all textboxes with class="col + index" and get the value of
    // each textbox 
    var item = $(this).find("input[type=text].col" + index).map(function(idx, dom) {
      return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    alert(JSON.stringify(item));

});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zu46bL24/

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

For your html, modify like this(using same class for all row and col):

```
<tr id='rowclass'>
<td class='colclass'>DEMO</td>
<td class='colclass'>DEMO</td>
</tr>
<tr id='rowclass'>
<td class='colclass'>DEMO</td>
<td class='colclass'>DEMO</td>
</tr>
<tr id='rowclass'>
<td class='colclass'>DEMO</td>
<td class='colclass'>DEMO</td>
</tr>
```

and, in js,

```
var rows = $(".rowclass").each(function(index){
    // for each row, 'this' is the current row
    // the following code will get the columns in current row.
    $(".colclass", this).each(function(){  /* get value of this col */  })
})
```

Comment: `$(".rowclass")` won't work because of `<tr id='rowclass'>`, it should be `<tr class='rowclass'>`

Comment: @Mavlarn the reason there's a number I'm trying to get the value per depth of the row for example the result must be :itemset1 = demo1{}demo2, itemset3 = demo3{}demo4, itemset4 = demo5{}demo6..

Answer (score 0):

here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ymzrocks/kat7hokr/3/

### NOTE: tr elements will not work properly without wrapping table element

html:

```
<table>
<tr id="row1">
<td class="col1">DEMO1</td>
<td class="col1">DEMO2</td>
</tr>
<tr id="row3">
<td class="col3">DEMO3</td>
<td class="col3">DEMO4</td>
</tr>
<tr id="row4">
<td class="col4">DEMO5</td>
<td class="col4">DEMO6</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

js:

```
$("tr[id^='row']").each(function()
{
    var rows = $(this).children();
    var set = '';

    rows.each(function()
    {
          set += $(this).text() + ' ';        
    });

    alert(set);
});
```

Comment: It works, but what if I was to put in on a textField

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("tr[id^=row]").each(function() {

    var id = this.id.replace('row', '');

    var item = $(this).find("td.col" + id).map(function(idx, dom) {
      return dom.innerHTML;
    }).get();

    alert(JSON.stringify(item));

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id='row1'>
    <td class='col1'>DEMO1.1</td>
    <td class='col1'>DEMO1.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='row3'>
    <td class='col3'>DEMO3.1</td>
    <td class='col3'>DEMO3.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='row4'>
    <td class='col4'>DEMO4.1</td>
    <td class='col4'>DEMO4.2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code it worked but what if I was to put the class on a input text field..

Comment: then replace `dom.innerHTML` with `$(dom).val()`